# replace breaks between brackets

Tags: php, regex

I need help.
Please assume the following PHP variable

```
$string="Hello this
is
me on [the
line
to
] have no clue";
```

Now I would like to replace the line breaks INSIDE the brackets with spaces to get this

```
Hello this
is
me on [the line to] have no clue
```

Any ideas?
I know how to handle all the line breaks, but I don't know how to only address the line breaks inside the brackets.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive lookahead based regex.

```
preg_replace('~\n(?=[^\[\]]*\])~', ' ', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tV1rL6/2)

Comment: Technically, that regex does not match newlines *inside* square brackets. Only if it is followed with `]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thought input contain balanced brackets.

Comment: if he wants the exact func then  he needs to use preg_replace_callback

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` to match `[...]` substrings and replace linebreaks in the matches only:

```
$s = "Hello this\nis\nme on [the\nline\nto\n] have no clue";
echo preg_replace_callback('/\[\s*([^][]*?)\s*]/', function($m){
    return "[" . str_replace("\n", " ", $m[1]) . "]";   
}, $s);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/bMTojH)

The [`\[\s*([^][]*?)\s*]`](https://regex101.com/r/bM0mB5/1) regex explanation:

- `\[` - open square bracket
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace
- `([^][]*?)` - as few as possible 0+ characters other than `[` and `]`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace
- `]` - closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

Just use [nl2br() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

```
 echo nl2br($string);
```

Hope this helps.